# $\lim_{x\to\ p}f(g(x))= f(\lim_{x\to\ p}g(x))$ with $f$ continuous; verification of proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $f$ is continuous in an interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $L \in  I$, then

\begin{align}
i)&& L&=\lim_{x\to p}g(x) &\implies&&\lim_{x\to\ p}f\big(g(x)\big)&= f\big(\lim_{x\to\ p}g(x)\big)
\\
ii)&& L&=\lim_{x\to\infty }g(x) &\implies&&\lim_{x\to\infty}f\big(g(x)\big)&= f\big(\lim_{x\to\infty }g(x)\big)
\end{align}

I tried prove that. Can somebody verify for me?

Proof:

i) Since $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=L$, then for all $\epsilon >0$, we have a $\delta$ such that 
$$
\left\lvert x-p\right\rvert <\delta\quad \implies\quad \left\lvert g(x)-L\right\rvert<\epsilon
$$

Since $f$ is continuous, then for all $\epsilon_1 >0$, we have a $\delta_1$

$$
\left\lvert g(x)-L\right\rvert<\delta_1\implies \left\lvert \,f(g(x))-f(L)\right\rvert <\epsilon_1
$$

It's enough to make $\epsilon$ equal to $\delta_1$. We can do that because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, so it can assume any real positive value. In case ii), $x \to \infty$, it's sufficient you switch $p$ for $\infty$ and do $x>\delta$. The rest is the same. The case $x \to -\infty$ is analogous to case $x \to \infty$.

If $\left\lvert \lim_{x\to p}g(x)\right\rvert= \infty$, then for all $\epsilon >0$, we have a $\delta$ such that 
$$
\left\lvert x-p\right\rvert<\delta \implies \left\lvert g(x)\right\rvert>\epsilon.
$$

Now we have to investigate the behaviour of $f(y)$ when $\left\lvert \lim_{x\to p}y\right\rvert= \infty$. In case $\left\lvert \lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)\right\rvert= \infty$, it's analogous. Therefore, in any cases above, you only have to investigate the limit of $g$.

If it's wrong, can somebody show me the correct proof?

Comment: First part looks good. A small remark, since in the end we want to find a $\delta$ for $\epsilon_1$, then I would say "It's enough to make $\epsilon$ equal to $\delta_1$" and not $\delta_1$ equal to $\epsilon$. For part two, I think you need to be more clear about the proof, the solution methods are the same as part one, it is testing you about using the two definitions for $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$.